# highcharts with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am new to these things. Using the code from URL: http://jsfiddle.net/sujay/UMeGS/ , I was trying to create a chart with my own data.

Using REST web service, I am able to get my data from database, which means when I click on the following link '`localhos:48095/WebApplication22/webresources/sample22.test15`' , I am getting json data as follows

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "stopped",
        "unit": "a",
        "val": 24
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "working",
        "unit": "a",
        "val": 59
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "status": "turning",
        "unit": "a",
        "val": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "status": "transport",
        "unit": "a",
        "val": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "status": "stopped",
        "unit": "b",
        "val": 336
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "status": "working",
        "unit": "b",
        "val": 212
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "status": "turning",
        "unit": "b",
        "val": 23
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "status": "transport",
        "unit": "b",
        "val": 1
    }
]
```

I have slightly modified code from http://jsfiddle.net/sujay/UMeGS/, in which I have used getJSON() to get data.

Below is the code.

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('localhos:48095/WebApplication22/webresources/sample22.test15', function (data) {
        var seriesData = [];
        var xCategories = [];
        var i, cat;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            cat = 'Unit ' + data[i].unit;
            if (xCategories.indexOf(cat) === -1) {
                xCategories[xCategories.length] = cat;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (seriesData) {
                var currSeries = seriesData.filter(function (seriesObject) {
                    return seriesObject.name == data[i].status;
                });
                if (currSeries.length === 0) {
                    seriesData[seriesData.length] = currSeries = {
                        name: data[i].status,
                        data: []
                    };
                } else {
                    currSeries = currSeries[0];
                }
                var index = currSeries.data.length;
                currSeries.data[index] = data[i].val;
            } else {
                seriesData[0] = {
                    name: data[i].status,
                    data: [data[i].val]
                }
            }
        }

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Stacked column chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: xCategories
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -100,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                            'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                series: seriesData
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But I am unable to see anything. Chart is not displayed. Please help me on this thing.

Comment: Use some kind of js debugging tool like console in Google Chrome. It will point syntax error / exception during execution of your code

Comment: First look gives following:  >> `for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ ...` - your `data` should be undefined here, because you get it in `getJSON()'s` callback... Put everything related to series calculation/highcharts rendering inside the `getJSON()'s` success callback

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I tried like that too by inserting everything inside getJSON()'s callback. After that also, chart is not displayed. Couldn't find where I am wrong.

Comment: Well man, i don't think somebody out there would do debug for you for reputation :) i pointed you to GChrome console - try to find out where the problem hides yourself.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. getJSON() is not executed when I try like this.  When I tried in another way getJSON is executed but its not getting loaded to chart.

Comment: Have you any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi, its Working now. Not sure what I changed, but suddenly its working!!